# Why would Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() return null?

Tags: c#, assemblies, embedded-resource, system.reflection

I am using a xml file as an embedded resource to load an XDocument. We are using the following code to get the appropriate file from the Assembly:

```
XDocument xd = new XDocument();
Assembly assembly = null;

try
{
    assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //Write exception to server event log
}

try
{
    if(assembly != null)
    {
        using(StreamReader sr = new 
            StreamReader(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("assemblyPath")))
        {
            using(XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(sr))
            {
                xd = XDocument.Load(xtr);
            }
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //Write exception to server event log
}
```

So when the code is deployed, we occasionally will go to the page and nothing will be loaded from the embedded document. When we check the event log, there is no error. If the user just refreshes the page, it'll load fine. This has lead me to think that, for some reason, `assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();` is ocassionally returning null, and the way the code is written this isn't an error. So, my question is why would `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();` be returning null? I found a couple articles talking about there being errors sometimes with unmanaged code, but this application is written in C# and deployed via setup project.

The code was originally written without error avoidance code. It was added to keep the users from getting error screens. The exceptions are written to the event log of the server.

Comment: Sorry, should have specified it a bit more. The catches are calling a method in a utility project to write the exception to the event log. The code to do so is used throughout the application and works. Also, the above code is in a method that is called during the page intialization.

Comment: So, after seeing that everyone seems to agree that GetExecutingAssembly() will not return null, I went back and and looked at the rest of the method. After some searching I found this article on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt(VS.85).aspx. In it is says GetManifestResourceStream() can return null if the resource isn't found or is inaccessible. Returning null to the using() construct wouldn't cause an exception. So we're going to deploy this and see if it's the culprit.

Comment: I hope that by "deploy" you mean "deploy a test version, to a test machine, using a test server", and that you are not in fact doing production pushes for "smoke tests" as the last comment seems to imply.  Next time your users start getting exceptions, I recommend fixing the bug that caused them instead of just suppressing the notification.

Comment: By "deploy" I mean it will go through another QA cycle. So far the issue has only been seen in production code though, so I doubt that will change now. As for fixing the bug, that's what I'm trying to do now.

Comment: "it was added to prevent users from getting error screens" - what do you mean?  Can you not change the app/web.config so users don't see errors like this?  Was there ever a resolution?

Answer (score 6):

go to the properties of the file whose path is mentioned and change the buildAction from content which is the default one to EmbeddedResource. Recompile and it should work.

Answer (score 5):

This is a perfect example of why it's an almost universally bad idea to eat exceptions, especially the top-level `System.Exception`.  The problem could be anywhere; more likely than not, the real problem is in your logging code.

Take out those empty `catch` blocks (or rethrow inside them with `throw;`) and see where the exception is *really* occurring.  And once you find the real problem and rewrite your code, rewrite it to catch only exceptions that you actually *know how to handle*.

`GetExecutingAssembly` will not return `null`, period.

Answer (score 3):

That can return null if you are launching your code from an unmanaged application (e.g. the NUnit Test runner): Try the following using the console:

```
[Test]
public void att()
{
    Assert.NotNull(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
}
```

Seeing as you've tagged it embedded, I'm guessing you're using some sort of bootloader, or interpreter to run your .Net app? That would probably be unmanaged (i.e. not .Net interpretted) and hence would return null.

See the documentation, section "Remarks: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly.aspx

Comment: Not that anyone's going to look at it now :/

Comment: I did I thought I going crazy this was very informative thanks.

Comment: Indeed, GetEntryAssembly() may return null when called from unmanaged code, but the OP asks about GetExecutingAssembly() and docs doesn't say anything about it returning null.

Answer (score 1):

When faced with a situation like this I try to really prove that the value returned was null. Try this:

```
try
{
    assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    Log.Write("Executing assembly is null: " + (assembly == null))
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //Write exception to server event log
}
```

I suspect it will always write "false", and something else is actually the problem - perhaps something you didn't include in your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access a file, go to that file, right click on it, go to it's properties, change it's **Build Action** to "**Embedded Resource**", then make sure the path your providing to the "**GetManifestResourceStream**" has the correct spelling.
The nullability happens mostly when the spelling of the path/file is wrong.